# How to stop mybatis print SQL script in console

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, mybatis, ibatis

I am using `mybatis-3.4.6` to execute sql script using `ScriptRunner`. It is printing whole script to the console. I am using `slf4j` for logging and I have included following lines in `logback.xml`. But it still printing.

```
<logger name="org.mybatis" level="WARN" />
<logger name="java.sql" level="WARN" />
```

Before `mybatis` I used `ibatis`. It didn't print script like this.

How can I stop printing script?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html?

Comment: As it says it first look for `slf4j`. But it won't pick or it just system out. I have checked the mentioned method call as well.

Comment: what is the effective level for the loggers named after the packages your mappers are in? `org.mybatis` from logging example may be misleading. If you mappers are in say `com.my.app.mappers` you need to set logging level of `com.my.app.mappers` to `WARN`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using method ScriptRunner.setLogWriter(null):

```
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(connection);
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scriptFile));
sr.setLogWriter(null);
sr.runScript(reader);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like a `System.out` to me. So I did following change to remove the console log. I don't this this is the best solution though.

```
PrintStream tmp = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // do nothing
    }
});
PrintStream console = System.out;
System.setOut(tmp);
// ScriptRunner call
System.setOut(console);
```